# About using update via mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

currently im so exhausted trying to figure why this function is not working as expected (inside a php class):

```
function actualizarPromos($nombre,$desc,$motivo,$id){
global $mysqli;
$sql="update promociones set nombre='".utf8_decode($nombre)."', desc='".utf8_decode($desc)."', motivo='".$motivo."' where id='".$id."'";
$mysqli->query($sql);
if($mysqli->insert_id>0){
            //It saved the data
    echo "Salvado";
}
else{
    //It didn't save the data   
        echo "No salvado";
    echo $mysqli->insert_id;
    echo "<br>".$sql;
}
```

}

I can´t get the function to update the contents of my db. I already tried to write de the SQL statement on phpmyadmin which is:

```
update promociones set nombre='cumple', desc='muy buen cumple', motivo='mCumple' where id='13';
```

And it doesn't execute at all. Anyone can help me out?. Thanks in advance!

Comment: are you sure you have a record with id = 13?

Comment: Yes! its a weird problem..I already executed an update via phpmyadmin and it gives me this code: `UPDATE  `micrositer`.`promociones` SET  `motivo` =  'mCumples' WHERE  `promociones`.`id` =13;´  I then wrote the same on my functions and still doesn't work..

Comment: when you run the code in phpmyadmin, you say it does not execute at all. does this mean - no errors and no change in database or you get an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`desc` is a [Revered Word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html#table-reserved-words-5.5.30) in MySQL, so your query is most likely failing. You need to escape it using the backtick - `

```
$sql="update promociones set nombre='".utf8_decode($nombre)."', `desc`='".utf8_decode($desc)."', motivo='".$motivo."' where id='".$id."'";
```